# C# Block function and Wait for Event to trigger. Also using async IAsyncOperation

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am currently having trouble with blocking a function and waiting for an event to trigger. Below is my code:

```
    bool isNotSwiped = true;
    bool isNotCancel = true;
    public Foo WaitForInputEvent(string strEventType, string PromptFor)
    {
        Foo ret = new Foo();

        MSR.MSR.Instance.Swipe += Instance_Swipe;

        while (isNotSwiped && isNotCancel)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1000));
        }

        (ret as Foo).MSRData = SwipeData;

        return ret;
    }

    public Foo SwipeData { get; set; }

    private void Instance_Swipe(object sender, Windows.Devices.PointOfService.MagneticStripeReaderBankCardDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        isNotSwiped = false;

        SwipeData = new Foo();

        (SwipeData as Foo).MSRData = CreateExtensibilityMagneticStripeReaderCardDataFromBankCard(e);

        MSR.MSR.Instance.Swipe -= Instance_Swipe;
    }
        (ret as Foo).MSRData = SwipeData;

        return ret;
    }

    public MSRInputEventArgs SwipeData { get; set; }

    private void Instance_Swipe(object sender, Windows.Devices.PointOfService.MagneticStripeReaderBankCardDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        isNotSwiped = false;

        SwipeData = new MSRInputEventArgs();

        (SwipeData as MSRInputEventArgs).MSRData = CreateExtensibilityMagneticStripeReaderCardDataFromBankCard(e);

        MSR.MSR.Instance.Swipe -= Instance_Swipe;
    }
```

When I swipe the card, the method Instance_Swipe does not trigger. Probably it is because of the while loop.

I tried using async void and it worked properly. However, I would still like to return Foo. We are also working with Windows Runtime so we cannot use Task. Below is another experimentation that I have tried:

```
    private TaskCompletionSource<Foo> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Foo>();
    public async IAsyncOperation<Foo> WaitForInputEvent(string strEventType, string PromptFor)
    {
        Foo ret = new Foo();

        MSR.MSR.Instance.Swipe += Instance_Swipe;
        await tcs.Task;

        (ret as Foo).MSRData = LastSwipedData;

        IAsyncOperation<Foo> test = tcs.Task.AsAsyncOperation<Foo>();

        //cannot find correct cast / return here
        return test;
    }
```

The problem is, I can't seem to find the proper return type for the async IAsyncOperation so it doesn't allow to compile. We trigger task completion source on the Instance_Swipe.

Can anyone recommend what is the best approach? This is a Universal Windows Store app.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `async` keyword *must* be used with a `Task`/`Task<T>`/`void` return type. It *cannot* be used with any other return type (yet).

So, to solve your problem, you just need to split the code into two methods: one that returns `Task<T>` and uses `async`, and one that returns `IAsyncOperation<T>`:

```
private async Task<Foo> DoWaitForInputEventAsync(string strEventType, string PromptFor)
{
  Foo ret = new Foo();

  MSR.MSR.Instance.Swipe += Instance_Swipe;
  await tcs.Task;

  (ret as Foo).MSRData = LastSwipedData;

  return ret;
}

public IAsyncOperation<Foo> WaitForInputEvent(string strEventType, string PromptFor)
{
  return DoWaitForInputEventAsync(strEventType, PromptFor).AsAsyncOperation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen! That solved the compile error. However, when I try to run it, the WaitForInputEvent already returns even if tcs.Task has not been Set yet. Is that really the intended behavior? I was hoping it would wait for the input. For example, in Javascript (using Chakra), if I call WaitForInputEvent, it won't proceed with the JS code until a swipe is performed.

Comment: @Water: You may find my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) helpful. The whole point of async code is that it can return before it's complete. However, the *task* returned by the async method won't complete until after `tcs.Task` completes. So if you consume the `WaitForInputEvent` with `await`, then your method will "asynchronously wait" (await) for it to complete.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I have made it work using promises on Javascript side.